# Mongo db installation on Mac osx with XAMPP and php 5.3 ext

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, database-connection, xampp

Hi I (think) just installed [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) to my local xampp machine.

I followed tutorials online and all seems to be done:

1. Moved pre-compiled `mongo.so` into `XAMPP/xampfiles/lib/php/php5.3/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`
2. Added this line of code into php.ini:

   > extension = mongo.so
3. Restarted Apache
4. Connected to localhost and I can see the mongo extension in `phpinfo()`
5. Went to http://localhost:27017 to see mongo interface and couldn't connect to it (Firefox returns an error)

Then I downloaded the [MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) client for mac osx to create/manage mongo databases, but it says socket error, and seems there is no connection to MongoDB

I (think) I installed also mongoDB itself

1. I created a directory: `XAMPP/xampfiles/var/mongodb`
2. I excracted tar MongoDB package file under `var/mongodb`so now I have `var/mongodb/bin`
3. From `var/mongodb` I launched this command:

> ./bin/mongod

And it returned:

```
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=946 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit 
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.3, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] git version: c206d77e94bc3b65c76681df5a6b605f68a2de05
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] build sys info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 dbexit: 
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Launching `./bin/mongo` also returns:

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.3
connecting to: test
Sun Sep 11 22:41:11 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Great, so you installed the Mongo PHP extension and a GUI client. Did you install MongoDB itself? — http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: ops :P i think not :P sec maybe later i will reply %)

Comment: the fact is that i can't find a good tutorial to install mongodb package inside XAMPP directories (if possible) :P , does you know oìhow to do?

Comment: `Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Sun Sep 11 22:40:32 dbexit:` This should tell you you the problem. You need to read the output of commands, not just run them blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start mongo with this command

```
mongod --dbpath=data
```

The --dbpath=data argument is where your database will be allocated, data is the path and could be something like /var/lib/mongodb/data or /data/mongodb.

And after that command you can go to http://localhost:27017 and see the mongodb monitor.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks it is running now ... but if i go to localhost:27017 it says: You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number

Comment: so i red on the terminal i can access to the monitor at localhost:28017   and there it is :)

Comment: You're connecting on the wrong port, start mongodb with this command: mongod --rest --dbpath=data and then connect on the 28017 port.